# Single real user - multiple permission sets (or local accounts)

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, user-accounts

I want to get a behavior where a single user can interactively switch permissions under which software is run without entering different and complicated passwords. E.g. I login using my account password and start web browser with low permissions, word with normal permissions and some installer with high permissions. I don't have to enter any passwords because I'm already logged in with my credentials. When I click "Run as" explorer.exe from user space sends a request to OS, I see a popup that allows me to confirm a permissions set that I need without entering any passwords.

What would be the best way to achieve something like this in Windows? I know I can partially solve it with Sandboxie but it feels like such thing should be achievable with just Windows accounts and ACL.

Comment: You can set PIN or Fingerprint as your Auth for a local account. Have you checked to see if these work for the "run as" functions?

Comment: Also, please edit your title. You don't get multiple permission sets on a single user. You want to ease the transition between users specifically when you run the Run As... function, which is quite different, and also probably actually doable.

Comment: Multiple accounts is just one of possible solutions. The title describes my goal, not the particular solution. I don't have a fingerprint device. PIN - I'll check.

Comment: No, I can't find a way to use pin code in with "run as"

Comment: @Vlad Just use multiple accounts. If you want to enter a PIN code to 'run as' then get a Yubikey and use that for authentication.